# Save code after every successful modification in WebStorm

Tags: github, version-control, webstorm

I have been writing some code in WebStorm for a practice project. But the problem is, I have written some code today and the application seems to work fine, then tomorrow when I am writing  some more code and the application is catching a bug which I am not able to debug, then I have to start all over again, which is pretty painful.

I would therefore like to save the code while it is working so that if required I can revert back to the last working version. I believe this is called version control and most people use GitHub for this, is it ?

I couldn't find a similar question. Maybe I am not using the correct keywords while searching.

Comment: It's called version control, but version control goes way further than that. And most people probably use git for that, but there are many other solutions. Github is an online service where you can host your git repositories, and providing some additional features on top of that (bug tracking, collaboration tools, etc.). To learn about git, read the git book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: For those who does not want/cannot to use proper VCS: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Local+History+in+PhpStorm